# How to clear all widgets from all sizers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have a GUI (created with wxPython) with a lot of TextCtrl and Some ComboBoxes. They a spread over different sizers.

At the moment i am doing this for all sizers i have:

```
    children = self.hbox.GetChildren() 
    for child in children:
        widget = child.GetWindow()
        if isinstance(widget, wx.TextCtrl):
            widget.Clear() 
        if isinstance(widget, wx.ComboBox):
            widget.SetValue("")
```

Is there a way to get all Sizers of an Class and do it then in an for loop or anything like that?

Comment: which python package do you use ? tkinter ?

Comment: wxPython. I edit my post to make if more clear!

Comment: you could add all TextCtrl to one list when you create them.

Comment: I know that, but this will end up in 60+ more lines of code. It will work, but i thinks its not very practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all children of the containing Window, not the Sizer, using
wx.Window.GetChildren. Which, of course, will only work if you have a flat structure, which I guess you don't. Therefore you could do it recursively:

```
def clean_up(window):
    if isinstance(window, TextCtrl):
        window.Clear()
    for i in window.GetChildren():
        clean_up(i)
```

By the way, both ComboBox and TextCtrl are descendants of TextEntry, therefore you can:

```
if isinstance(window, TextEntry):
    window.Clear()
```

Comment: `ComboBox and TextCtrl are ancestors of TextEntry`. That is a nice catch!